# No mm_workpace bit in User Settings when trying to set up MavensMate in Sublime Text 3

Tags: mavensmate, force.com-ide

I'm trying to get MavensMate up and running, but when I try and load the User settings under the MavensMate header there a couple of things different from the Apex Academy demo I'm trying to follow.

Firstly, the option is 'User Plugin Settings', not 'User' as shown in the demo

Secondly, the page looks prett different, with no mm_workspace line to edit.

And if I try to bypass this step and try and create a new project, i get the error "Request to the local MavensMate server failed, please ensure MavensMate Desktop is installed and running"

Comment: Please link to any materials you reference...

Comment: I can't. It's a paid for course on Plural Sight

Comment: You need to actually start the MavensMate app separately. Have you done that?